# Duplicate json fields trimmed while sending request using python requests library

Tags: python, http, request

I am using python requests library for sending json request.
My json is having multiple some keys more than once.

By default requests library is eliminating the duplicated field and sending only one entry for each field.

Please let me know if there is some way to send the exact json file.

My Reqest:

"q": [
    {
      "xyz": "myfield",
      "abc": {
        "val1": "v1",
        "val2": "v2"
      },
      "sha1": "1895d1887132818d010deebe61e0c475983ac5d0",
      "sha1": "2895d1887132818d010deebe61e0c475983ac5d1"
    }
]

Request Sent by python's request libraray

"q": [
    {
      "xyz": "myfield",
      "abc": {
        "val1": "v1",
        "val2": "v2"
      },
      "sha1": "1895d1887132818d010deebe61e0c475983ac5d0"

```
}
```

]

So one of the sha1 is filtered out.I want both of them to be sent as a part of request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the concept of keys in dictionary. For a dictionary, `key` is unique to fetch the corresponding value. Duplicate keys does not make sense. Don't know why you would want this. Still, 2 ways to solve this can be:-

1. Rename the other key `sha1_1` or something that makes more sense.
2. Use a list to send all values of `sha1` key. Something like:-

   "q": [ { "xyz": "myfield", "abc": { "val1": "v1", "val2": "v2" }, "sha1": ["1895d1887132818d010deebe61e0c475983ac5d0", "2895d1887132818d010deebe61e0c475983ac5d1"] } ]